# Android ApiDemos sample application errors

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have created Android ApiDemos sample application in my Eclipse IDE, but it complains numerous errors (69 errors and 100 warnings).

I have properly included the recommended depended jar `android-support-v4.jar`.

I have tried various build targets, from Eclair to Jelly Bean.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your project: Project > Clean